# Questions about dma_sync_single_for_cpu() / dma_sync_single_for_device()

Tags: c, linux-kernel, dma

My code uses stream DMA APIs to map an allocated buffer to DMA region like below:

```
void perform_dma(void *buffer)
{
    dma_map_single(buffer...  DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);  <- map buffer to physical address

    ring_doorbell()  -> notify device to read DMA content

    // wait until DMA is done or wake up by interrupts 
    .....

    dma_unmap_single(... , DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL)   <- unmap buffer
}
```

The DMA direction is BIDIRECTIONAL and `buffer` is allocated, filled by caller before `perform_dma()` is called and freed after it is done.

Should I use

- `dma_sync_single_for_device()` after `dma_map_single()` is called (but before notifying device to perform DMA)

and

- `dma_sync_single_for_cpu()` right before `dma_unmap_single()` (as the buffer would be read by caller after `perform_dma()`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can lookup in here [in this KernelTLV presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/kerneltlv/dma-survivial-guide) (slide 13). There's an explanation there regarding buffer responsibility.

In the example in the presentation it is said you (the driver) can alter the buffer content after `dma_sync_single_for_cpu()` and return ownership to the device by calling `dma_sync_single_for_device()`.

It's a question of ownership. `dma_sync_single_for_device()` grants ownership to the DMA controller where `dma_sync_single_for_cpu()` gains ownership back.